# BigCommerce API PHP - Authorizing?

Tags: php, api, ssl, xampp, bigcommerce

I'm using the PHP library of the BigCommerce API. I am seeming to have trouble and keep getting error messages. I am not sure if this is an authorization issue or if I'm missing something.

I'm using XAMPP and install composer along with the BigCommerce PHP package I need. I followed this guide: https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php

So here's what my code looks like (credentials X'd out):

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;


    Bigcommerce::configure(array(

        'store_url' => 'http://store-XXXXXXXX.mybigcommerce.com',
        'username' => 'admin',
        'api_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ));


$ping = Bigcommerce::getTime();


if (!$ping ) {
$error = Bigcommerce::getLastError();
print_r($error);
}   


?>
```

This returns: `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [status] => 400 [message] => The connection is not secure. API requests must be made via HTTPS. ) )`

I was wondering if it had to do with the "store_url" I used in the configuring. So I changed it to the front-end URL (real name of my store), and upon doing so I get this message instead:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Bigcommerce\Api\NetworkError' with message 'SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\PSC_BigC\bigcommerce-api-php-master\src\vendor\bigcommerce\api\src\Bigcommerce\Api\Connection.php:274 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\PSC_BigC\bigcommerce-api-php-master\src\vendor\bigcommerce\api\src\Bigcommerce\Api\Connection.php(368): Bigcommerce\Api\Connection->handleResponse() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\PSC_BigC\bigcommerce-api-php-master\src\vendor\bigcommerce\api\src\Bigcommerce\Api\Client.php(423): Bigcommerce\Api\Connection->get('https://psc-dev...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\PSC_BigC\bigcommerce-api-php-master\src\test.php(19): Bigcommerce\Api\Client::getTime() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\PSC_BigC\bigcommerce-api-php-master\src\vendor\bigcommerce\api\src\Bigcommerce\Api\Connection.php on line 274
```

Comment: Error states clearly, you need to use https for the 'store_url'. Continue to use the '.mybigcommerce.com' url but with https.

Comment: Correct. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because youre using a self signed certificate.

you need to configure Bigcommerce to ignore the warning.

```
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);
```

this effectively turns checking off in the cURL client it seems to be using.

Answer (score 3):

The error states : "API requests must be made via HTTPS."

Change your store URL to "http**s**://store-XXXXXXXX.mybigcommerce.com" as it is secure.

Example from the docs (store URL needs to be HTTPS).

https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php

```
Bigcommerce::configure(array(
    'store_url' => 'https://store.mybigcommerce.com',
    'username'  => 'admin',
    'api_key'   => 'd81aada4xc34xx3e18f0xxxx7f36ca'
));
```